# Use Instagram API to read statistics information from my account?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an Instagram account.
Can I use Instagram API to read statistics information(picture liked number) for my Instangram account?

Or the Api is just for app interacting directly with users?

Answer (score 3):

### **EDIT 31.05.2018:**

It is not possible to get like counts anymore: [API Endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

---

It is possible and really easy with Instagram API.

You can find the related information [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/).

Also, left menu of [API Endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) page will guide you for other things that you can do with the API.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. As I read the API docs, it seems that the review process for the request of using API is stricter. I don't know if an app that only gets the statistics infor will be accepted or not by Instagram

Comment: Yes there is a review process but I don't think that it will be too strict.